# Why does string with special characters behaves differently in GET and POST methods?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

By using jQuery, I am trying to save my string array in backend and following is my approach.

1.Using jQuery ajax sending array.

```
var tagTexts = $(ul li.select2-selection__choice")
                   .toArray()
                   .map(function(i){
                       return i.innerText;
                   });
tagTexts = JSON.stringify(tagTexts);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST' ,
    url: '/tag/tagList',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        tagTexts: tagTexts
    },
    error: function(err) {
       console.log(err);
    },
    success: function(response) {
        //Process Response
    }

});
```

2.In backend it is retrieved as follows:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/tag/tagList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveTagList(HttpServletRequest request,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "searchTagTexts", required = false)String tagListString) {
   try 
   {
        List<String> tagTexts = (List<String>)mapper.readValue(tagListString, new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
        System.out.println(tagTexts);
        String response = tagService.saveTags(tagTexts);
        return response;
   } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
}
```

In this scenario everything is working fine.

**Trying same scenario with GET option:**

I have tried the above scenario using `GET` option (like adding type: 'GET' in ajax call and setting method = RequestMethod.GET in @RequestMapping annotation).

Following will be the value of **tagTexts** while making ajax call:

```
"["Drone", "Richard Feynman, PHD", "Yatch","Tik—Tok"]"
```

In java execution (backend) this gets displayed as follows:

[image]

I am getting unexpected strings in back end. What would be the reason for this behaviour??

Comment: It's because in a GET request the data is URL encoded and the EM dash will be encoded to `%E2%80%93`. Your server text encoding seems unable to decode that.

Comment: — is https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%80%94

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your answer seems to be reasonable. Please post the same with better explanation so that I can accept it.